# Joomla 2.5: Few menus with same links

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

SEF - on

I have 3 menus:

#### Main menu:

- Home
- Portfolio
- - People (type: Menu Item Alias, menu item: "People")
- - Commercial (type: Menu Item Alias, menu item: "Commercial")
- Contacts

#### People menu:

- People
- - Faces
- - Man
- - Woman
- - Childs

#### Commercial menu:

- Commercial
- - Cars
- - Houses
- - Celebrities

But type "Menu Item Alias" not working.

I've got /people/childs/ instead of /portfolio/people/childs/

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Install module [Extended Menu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/tree-menus/163).

In this module you must configure menu item id for Split parameter.

We have many sub-menu modules with only one menu structure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making People (in the People menu) an alias of People (in the Main menu)?

That should give the /portfolio/people/childs/ structure that you want.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it's not working.
I still got /people/childs/ or {current_time}/childs/